# HtmlSpanner for Android usage (NightWhistler)

Tags: android, html, textview

I'm using NightWhistler's HtmlSpanner to render my html content in TextView. I called:

```
HtmlSpanner htmlspanner = new HtmlSpanner();
Spannable text = htmlspanner.fromHtml(content);      
mContentTx.setText(text);
```

What I get for the output is just images, and no text. When I print out "text", it shows empty string.

Can someone please advise! Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Sardor, that's the full part for HtmlSpanner.
When I use Android's Html.fromHtml(), it shows only the content but not the images.

`code` Spanned spanned_tx = Html.fromHtml(content, imgGetter, new HtmlHandleTag()); `code`

Answer (score 4):

There is this issue that cause HtmlSpanner produces blank output when using HtmlCleaner 2.4

[Doesn't work with HtmlCleaner 2.4](https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner/issues/8)

Try using HtmlCleaner 2.2